# Would i be able to work with Angular 8 after learning Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I have learned Angular 4, are there major differences between it and Angular 8 ? and what will i need to learn in addition to what i learned in angular 4 ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Just try it out.

Comment: I have no idea what is that. Opinion based?

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@lifenshades/difference-among-angular-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-breakdown-new-features-and-changes-811fb5f8e6f0).

Comment: Change the title, which is primarly opinion based

Comment: For the record, I don't think this is really opinion-based, but it should be closed for being too broad anyway and there were already 3 votes for opinion-based so majority wins on the close reason...

Comment: this is a question alot of students ask, so it is indeed useful to have it here, but if majority is more valuable than facts then.. ok !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: yes. Check this out: https://update.angular.io/#4.0:8.0 its used to update your angular, its basically listing what changed between the versions.